# write() printing input to stdout instead of pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I have a question regarding write() and pipes.
I have narrowed down my problem to these two code fragments, one for writing into the pipe, one for checking if anything happened:

Parent Process:

```
char* reply = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
addchar(reply);
if (shm->nextStone == -1) {
  sprintf(reply, "PLAY %s", shm->nextField);
} else {
  sprintf(reply, "PLAY %s,%d", shm->nextField, shm->nextStone);
}

err = write(fd[1], reply, 15);
(...)
```

Child Process:

```
rc = select(biggest + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
(...)
else if (FD_ISSET(pipe, &fds)) {
  doMove(sock, buffer, fd); //read is going to be called here
}
```

It works just fine most of the time, but after the programm has run a while write() behaves strangely:

Instead of writing the input to the pipe(fd), it just prints the input to the console like printf.

FD_ISSET returns false because nothing has been written to the pipe and my program times out. I simply can't figure out why and haven't found anything regarding write() randomly printing. Does anyone know why it does this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just assign fd[0] in the child process and don't do anything with fd[1] other than close and write. Could this be the problem? Here is the part where my partner assigned fd[0] in the child process. Also buffer flow isn't an issue I think, it never goes beyond PLAY A3,2 for example

```
    int waitforfds(int sock, char* buffer, sharedmem * shm, int fd[]) {
    int rc, size, status, biggest;
    int pipe = fd[0];
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval timeout;

    if (pipe > sock) {
            biggest = pipe;
    } else {
            biggest = sock;
    }
     do {
           (...)
            FD_SET(sock, &fds);
            FD_SET(pipe, &fds);
           (...)
            rc = select(biggest + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
            if (rc == -1) {
                    perror("Error, select failed! \n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;

            if (rc > 0) {

                    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fds)) {
                           (...)
                            }


                    } else if (FD_ISSET(pipe, &fds)) {
                            doMove(sock, buffer, fd);

                    }

            } else if (rc == 0) {
                    perror("Select timed out!. \n");
            }
    }
    while (rc != 0);

     (...)
```

2nd EDIT: 
I think I figured it out I declared fd globally above the main function and for some reason that led to undefined behaviour. I really don't know why but after I changed it, it seems to work again. Also thanks to Jonathan for telling me about fd potentially having the value 0.

```
   int fd[2];

   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
```

to

```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   int fd[2];
```

Comment: where have you opened the pipe? show where is `fd[1]` assigned.

Comment: Certain `sprintf(reply,...` did not overflow `reply`?  15 appears small.

Comment: The obvious way for that to happen would be if `fd[1]` were overwritten with either 1 or 2; the not so obvious value of 0 would also often work (and is perhaps more likely as the value in `fd[1]`) because the way that terminals are connected often means that standard input is actually writable and standard output and standard error are actually readable.  So, check on the value in `fd[1]`...and if it got overwritten, you'll have to track down why.

Comment: Interesting thanks! I just checked and fd[1] is 0 before I write when the error happens. Normally it is 5. I will try to figure out why

Comment: @user3215972: Use a watchpoint in your debugger. It's best if it is a hardware watchpoint, which it usually is. How that works is the hardware is asked to interrupt whenever a particular memory location is written to. It'll even catch it if the value is being overwritten by a buffer overflow.